# jaxb unmarshaller with and without JAXBElement

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I've got following JAXB annotated classes (generated with XJC)

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "ReplicateTransactionDataNotificationType", namespace = "http://esb.pkobp/adapter/calypso/tradekast/transaction", propOrder = {
        "operationContext",
        "transactionData"
    })
    public class ReplicateTransactionDataNotificationType
        implements Serializable
    {

        @XmlElement(name = "OperationContext", required = true)
        protected OperationContextType operationContext;
        @XmlElement(name = "TransactionData")
        protected TransactionDataType transactionData;

        public OperationContextType getOperationContext() {
            return operationContext;
        }

        public void setOperationContext(OperationContextType value) {
            this.operationContext = value;
        }

        public TransactionDataType getTransactionData() {
            return transactionData;
        }

        public void setTransactionData(TransactionDataType value) {
            this.transactionData = value;
        }

    }
```

When unmarshalling it in the following way, everything works just fine:

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(ReplicateTransactionDataNotificationType.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller =  ctx.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<ReplicateTransactionDataNotificationType> result;
    result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes())), ReplicateTransactionDataNotificationType.class);
```

When unmarshalling it in the following way, it crashes with the exception

```
(ReplicateTransactionDataNotificationType)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlString));
```

Exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://esb.pkobp/adapter/calypso/tradekast/transaction", local:"caltradetran_ReplicateTransactionDataNotification"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:642)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1049)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:478)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:459)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:148)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:194)
    at myPackage.XMLTranslationResolver.main(KondorXMLTranslationResolver.java:120)
```

Could sombody explain this weird behaviour?

The XML file being unmarshalled is pasted below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<caltradetran:caltradetran_ReplicateTransactionDataNotification xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                                                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                                                                xmlns:caltradetran="http://esb.pkobp/adapter/calypso/tradekast/transaction"
                                                                xmlns:tran="http://esb.pkobp/cdm/treasury/transaction">
   <OperationContext>
      <RequestID>98573c9c-6167-4edb-a5ff-8ad3db9983ef</RequestID>
      <EventSource>KONDOR</EventSource>
      <EventDate>2012-11-13T12:13:42.937+01:00</EventDate>
   </OperationContext>
   <TransactionData>
      <ExternalReferenceKp>FWD57658</ExternalReferenceKp>
      <DealTableID>95</DealTableID>
      <Action>INS</Action>
      <TransactionAdditionalData>
         <ExternalReferenceKp>FWD57658</ExternalReferenceKp>
         <ExternalReferenceTr/>
         <ClientPID>123456</ClientPID>
         <ProductSubType>FXForward</ProductSubType>
         <SourceSystem>Kondor+</SourceSystem>
         <AdditionalParameterList>
            <Parameter>
               <Name>TransactionType</Name>
               <ValueType>string</ValueType>
               <StringValue>Spekulacja</StringValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
               <Name>ReceiveFrom_AccountNo</Name>
               <ValueType>string</ValueType>
               <StringValue>test</StringValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
               <Name>ReceiveFrom_SettleMethod</Name>
               <ValueType>string</ValueType>
               <StringValue>DIRECT</StringValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
               <Name>ReceiveTo_AccountNo</Name>
               <ValueType>string</ValueType>
               <StringValue>test</StringValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
               <Name>ReceiveTo_SettleMethod</Name>
               <ValueType>string</ValueType>
               <StringValue>DIRECT</StringValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
               <Name>PayFrom_AccountNo</Name>
               <ValueType>string</ValueType>
               <StringValue>test</StringValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
               <Name>PayFrom_SettleMethod</Name>
               <ValueType>string</ValueType>
               <StringValue>DIRECT</StringValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
               <Name>PayTo_AccountNo</Name>
               <ValueType>string</ValueType>
               <StringValue>test</StringValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
               <Name>PayTo_SettleMethod</Name>
               <ValueType>string</ValueType>
               <StringValue>DIRECT</StringValue>
            </Parameter>
         </AdditionalParameterList>
      </TransactionAdditionalData>
      <ForwardDeal>
         <FILE>1105_133831_INS.00057658.00072904</FILE>
         <ACTION>INS</ACTION>
         <TRANS_ID>72904</TRANS_ID>
         <XACTKEY>350000000353842604</XACTKEY>
         <OPERATIONS>3</OPERATIONS>
         <MAIN_DEAL_TABLE_ID>95</MAIN_DEAL_TABLE_ID>
         <MAIN_DEAL_ID>57658</MAIN_DEAL_ID>
         <ORIGINAL_TYPE_OF_EVENT>K</ORIGINAL_TYPE_OF_EVENT>
         <DEALS_INSTRUMENT_ID>13</DEALS_INSTRUMENT_ID>
         <DEALS_OPERATION_ID>0</DEALS_OPERATION_ID>
         <MESSAGE_SOURCE>RealTime</MESSAGE_SOURCE>
         <DEALS_OPERATION>INSERT</DEALS_OPERATION>
      </ForwardDeal>
   </TransactionData>
</caltradetran:caltradetran_ReplicateTransactionDataNotification>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the `ObjectFactory` class when creating the `JAXBContext`.  The `ObjectFactory` contains the `@XmlElementDecl` annotations which contain root element information.  I would recommend creating the `JAXBContext` on the package name of the generated model.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Comment: OK, this, together with the blog entry, answers my question a bit. When I created JAXBContext with package declaration, it worked, and I got JAXBElement in return. When I added @XmlRootElement to my class, I got in return the domain object. I still need to figure out how to handle namespaces with JAXB

Comment: @user1200125 - I wrote the following about JAXB and namespaces that should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Thanks very much! All I was missing was the @XmlElementDecl bit, but thanks to this post, I have it all working!

Comment: I used the information at the following link to fix a similar error I was getting trying to unmarshal an xml fragment: https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/03/15/unmarshalling-an-xml-fragment-representing-a-jaxb-object-without-xmlrootelement/